# NameError in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python. Whenever I am using Try Except the NameError shows up. It works perfectly when there is no exception handling.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.error import HTTPError


try:
    htm = urlopen('https://uiit.tech/placements/placements.pp')
except HTTPError as e:
    print(e)


bs = BeautifulSoup(htm, 'html.parser')
print(bs.h1)
```

output Error

```
HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Traceback (most recent call last):line 12, in <module>
bs = BeautifulSoup(htm.read(), 'html.parser')
NameError: name 'htm' is not defined
```

Comment: Where do you get `NameError`? Please add the full error message.

Comment: To avoid getting `NameError` you can use `htm = ""` just before `print(e)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the attempt to work with `htm` inside the `try` section. Currently, due to exception it is never set.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.error import HTTPError

try:
    htm = urlopen('https://uiit.tech/placements/placements.pp')  
    bs = BeautifulSoup(htm, 'html.parser')
    print(bs.h1)
except HTTPError as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Thanks It worked. This NameError was due to the scope of the variable in TRY block.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:

    print(e)
```